# How is the vim-plug managing my vim plugins?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

When I check my `.vim` directory, I found that all the plugins installed with `vim-plug` is sitting in the `.vim/plugged` directory. In this case, how did vim load these plugins? If I have a same plugin normally installed, then which one will have a higher propriety to be loaded?

Comment: Note: Stackoverflow also has a beta site for "vi and vim". Check it out!

Comment: Priority is determined by `'rtp'` option. Look into this variable to know in which order things are loaded (see BTW `:h 'rtp'`). Then, your next question is probably "how is it filled?". Well. That's thanks to 'rtp' that your plugin manager registers plugins living in separate folders.

Comment: Isn't the whole point of plugin managers to shield you from those concepts?

Comment: @romainl, ..and curiosity's to expose you to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`plug#begin(...)`](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug/blob/master/plug.vim#L113) function sets the "home" path for the plugin (`vim-plug` is a plugin too),

```
  if a:0 > 0
    let s:plug_home_org = a:1
    let home = s:path(fnamemodify(expand(a:1), ':p'))
  ...
```

and the function [`plug#end()`](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug/blob/master/plug.vim#L193) goes through the list of plugins defined (via `plug#()`), and keeps them in a dictionary:

```
  for name in g:plugs_order
  ...
         if has_key(plug, 'on')
      let s:triggers[name] = { 'map': [], 'cmd': [] }
      for cmd in s:to_a(plug.on)
        if cmd =~? '^<Plug>.\+'
          if empty(mapcheck(cmd)) && empty(mapcheck(cmd, 'i'))
            call s:assoc(lod.map, cmd, name)
```

then finally manipulates the `runtimepath` and `source`s each one of the plugins by calling (eventually) [`s:lod()`](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug/blob/master/plug.vim#L465):

```
  for [cmd, names] in items(lod.cmd)
    execute printf(
    \ 'command! -nargs=* -range -bang %s call s:lod_cmd(%s, "<bang>", <line1>, <line2>, <q-args>, %s)',
    \ cmd, string(cmd), string(names))
  endfor
```

You can figure out the order in which plugins are loaded from `vim-plug`'s code.

Answer (score 0):

Loading a plugin is nothing more than sourcing the script file(s). The script file could be anywhere.

Usually a plugin has a flag (g:variable e.g.)  to detect if the script is already loaded. So it won't be loaded twice. However, if your plugin doesn't have this mechanism, it could be loaded twice.